# What are some Line detection/recognition algorithms used in machine learning?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-matching, pattern-recognition

I'v looked at Hough Transform, but I'd like a machine learning classifier that would achieve the same purpose: detect unique lines from a given 2D vector or image. The closest I could think of was k-NN, but that would give me neighbors around a cluster instead of those that fall in a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to do would be to train a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN). The different convolution layers should produce maps that will detect small portions of lines within different orientations. And when recombined all together it should detect straight lines. As I said into my comments, it can even reconnect discontinued lines.

If you are also interested by twisted lines (so not only straight), you can add a Transformer layer, which is going to apply elastic deformations during the training. These transformations will twist the line detectors, making them sensitive to twisted lines.

Comment: My understanding of CNN's would be different: they provide general shape recognition. But searching for straight lines is a precise structure better suited to Hough (as mentioned in OP), Gaussian filtering, Marr-Hildreth edge, etc.

Comment: I've already trained one for discontinued lines reconnection. If it can reconnect lines, it can detect them.

Comment: Ok well that shows it can work.  Would you mind to provide some amount of information about *why* the CNN would be a useful choice for this type of problem?

Comment: I've add more explanations. Does it make it more clear?

Comment: Well I can not honestly say there were enough details here.. but I upvoted anyways. Feel free to add more.